# Map loading and writing, which Reader/Writer should I use?

Tags: android, file, maps

I'm doing my first game for a school project. I'm not new when talking about programming Android, but I'm not sure which `reader` and `writer` (BufferedReader, Scanner, DataInputStrem) I need to use when loading a game map.
Also, should I make a program for writing maps? Or just write on notepad?

Edit:The game is a boxman, and if someone is interested [here](http://code.google.com/p/move-the-garbage/) is it's site.Don't eat me please...